# Command "make" (used for making makefiles) cannot find the path specified

Tags: makefile, pdcurses

Firstly, I'm using Windows 7

I have been trying to install the pdcurses-extended library

found here: https://github.com/Bill-Gray/PDCurses

Which requires to make a makefile (more specifically the wingui/Makefile.mng)

I have downloaded the GNUwin which contains make for windows

found here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm

I have moved both folders to the root of C:\ (C:\PDCurses-master and C:\GnuWin32)

I launched the cmd and navigated to the folder where make.exe is located at

```
cd C:\GnuWin32\bin
```

Than I used the make command to make the makefile

```
make -f C:\PDCurses-master\wingui\Makefile.mng WIDE=Y
```

which failed with the following error

```
C:\PDCurses-master\wingui\Makefile.mng:14: ../version.mif: No such file or directory
C:\PDCurses-master\wingui\Makefile.mng:15: ../libobjs.mif: No such file or directory
The system cannot find the path specified.
C:\PDCurses-master\wingui\Makefile.mng:171: ../makedist.mif: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `../makedist.mif'.  Stop.
```

It seems that files version.mif & libobjs.mif & makedist.mif cannot be found, but when I checked, the files were there (location C:\PDCurses-master)

Does anyone see what I have done wrong. I am open to suggestions and will even use a different make if instructed to.

After trying @StephaneM suggestion, it helped, but that just generated a different error

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
gcc -c -O4 -Wall -pedantic -I.. -DPDC_WIDE ../pdcurses/addch.c
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, gcc -c -O4 -Wall -pedantic -I.. -DPDC_WIDE ../pdcurses/addch.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [addch.o] Error 2
```

again, it seems that make cannot find the files addch.c, but the file is there (full directory: C:\PDCurses-master\pdcurses\addch.c)

Comment: I believe it's saying that it can't find gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess: your current directory is `C:\GnuWin32\bin` so `../version.mif` is equivalent to `C:\GnuWin32\version.mif`

Try to launch your make like that:

```
cd C:\PDCurses-master\wingui
C:\GnuWin32\bin\make -f .\Makefile.mng WIDE=Y
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but it just generated a different error. I have edited my main post to display the new error message (because I don't know how to format code in the comments).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @StephaneM, I was able to solve the first part of my problem.

And thanks to @William_Mcbrine for helping me solve the second part (and also for making the original PDCurses library).

I indeed have been missing the gcc command, so after searching for it for a bit, I have found out I already have installed MinGW (which comes with both mingw32-make and gcc) when I was installing Code::Blocks. I have set a path to C:\MinGW\bin and ran the command:

```
cd C:\PDCurses-master\wingui
mingw32-make -f Makefile.mng WIDE=Y
```

Which ultimatly worked without generating any error.